# Swift - UiPickerView autoscrolls to top on reload

Tags: swift, uipickerview

First time asking a question so stick with me if I forget something.

So I have a UiPicker that has a tapRecognizer. As the user taps I'm updating the colour of tapped rows and ideally would like to Reload on tap to update the colour immediately. However, this autoscrolls to the top of the picker for some reason.

Selecting the row immediately after reloading components almost worked but still scrolls to the top around 50% of the time.

I've had a good play around with it but can't figure out a way to ReloadAllComponents or ReloadComponent without autoscrolling to the top. 
Anyone got any ideas for where it's mucked up?

Thanks

```
 @objc func pickerTapped(tapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if tapRecognizer.state == .ended {
        let rowHeight = self.RightPicker.rowSize(forComponent: 0).height
        let selectedRowFrame = self.RightPicker.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: (self.RightPicker.frame.height - rowHeight) / 2)
        let userTappedOnSelectedRow = selectedRowFrame.contains(tapRecognizer.location(in: self.RightPicker))

        if userTappedOnSelectedRow {
             PickerNumber = self.RightPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
                if(pickerSelectedData.contains(pickerData[PickerNumber]) != true){
                    pickerSelectedData.append(pickerData[PickerNumber])
                    pickerSelectedD[PickerNumber] = 1
                }
                else{
                    if let itemToRemoveIndex1 = pickerSelectedData.index(of: pickerData[PickerNumber]) {
                        pickerSelectedData.remove(at: itemToRemoveIndex1)
                    }
                    pickerSelectedD[PickerNumber] = 0
                }
                RightPicker.reloadAllComponents()
                RightPicker.selectRow(PickerNumber, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
```

Extra Codes

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        RightPicker.reloadAllComponents();
    }
```

One more

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: I believe it is scrolling to top because of reloadAllComponents method of UIPickerView.

Answer (score 0):

Problematic part seems to be `reloadAllComponents`.

You may try using [reloadComponent:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614385-reloadcomponent?language=objc). This will load only specific element.